# $inlinecount and $count missing in new OData API?

Tags: 2013, bug, odata, rest

can anybody verify that in the new OData endpoint of SharePoint 2013 found at /_api/ does not implement the keywords $inlinecount and $count? 
ListData.svc has it implemented.

Example:

/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$inlinecount=allpages <-- No count in output

/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/listname?$inlinecount=allpages <-- Has count in output.

Comment: $skip is not working, too ...

Answer (score 5):

I have various parameters for testing ODATA API

And have tested:

"_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/itemcount"

result:
[image: item count]

Is equivalent of "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents/$count"
the result is fast and immediate:
[image]

with this "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/listname?$inlinecount=allpages"

add to result as field called "count", see image below:
[image: count allpages]

> You can clearly see the differences of these three parameters?

Later I will testing the other.

Thanks.